# ReactJs how to convert svg element into an .eps file?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, type-conversion

I can't find a suitable library that can convert svg element on the page to .eps file. I tried various options that chatgpt offers, but this creates an not valid eps file. How to do this correctly? I tried such code, Photoshop and Adobe Illustrator do not open this file, but online eps viewer fviewer.com/view-eps opens it. Maybe there are some other ideas?

```
const dataURItoBlob = (dataURI) => {
      const byteString = atob(dataURI.split(",")[1]);
      const mimeString = dataURI.split(",")[0].split(":")[1].split(";")[0];
      const ab = new ArrayBuffer(byteString.length);
      const ia = new Uint8Array(ab);
      for (let i = 0; i < byteString.length; i++) {
        ia[i] = byteString.charCodeAt(i);
      }
      return new Blob([ab], { type: mimeString });
    };

    const svgElement = svgRef.current;
    const svgXml = new XMLSerializer().serializeToString(svgElement);
    const canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
    canvas.width = svgElement.clientWidth;
    canvas.height = svgElement.clientHeight;
    const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
    const svgBlob = new Blob([svgXml], { type: "image/svg+xml" });
    const img = new Image();
    img.onload = () => {
      ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0);
      const epsDataUri = canvas.toDataURL("image/eps", 1.0);
      const blob = dataURItoBlob(epsDataUri);
      const a = document.createElement("a");
      a.href = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
      a.download = "image.eps";
      a.click();
      window.URL.revokeObjectURL(a.href);
    };

    img.src = URL.createObjectURL(svgBlob);
```

Comment: Canvas todataurl doesn't create eps files.  It will be a png file if it doesn't support the mime type.

Comment: Also eps files are vector based, converting a canvas that is raster based to a vector format makes no sense,  svg to eps would be more appropriate.

Comment: There are a lot of tools. You could investigate how those websites work, like this one: https://offlineconverter.com/image/svg-to-eps/

Comment: And another typical way, send it to the server and do a backend conversion using any backend tool.

Comment: Could it be you're actually struggling with generated/optimized svg files that can't be opened it editors or loaded for print production? If so, a conversion to a proprietary format like eps is rather complicated an probably won't solve the problem. Also, eps won't "automagically" solve problems like font-embedding or cmyk color conversion. Quite likely you're better off with sanitizing the svg or converting it to pdf via a lib like [svg2pdf.js](https://github.com/yWorks/svg2pdf.js). We shouldn't waste our time on this - albeit some graphic design folks still believe in .eps "superpowers".